# What is the difference between a . a , and a { in a php echo of variables?

Tags: php, variables, echo

In PHP how do you know if you should use each form of echo, and what is the proper uses for each:

with the period:

```
 echo"<div>
        <img src='".$row['image']."'>
        ".$row['text']."
    </div>
```

with the comma:

```
echo"<div>
    <img src='",$row['image'],"'>
    ",$row['text'],"
</div>
```

with the {}:

```
echo"<div>
    <img src='{$row['image']}'>
    {$row['text']}
</div>
```

preset:

```
$image=$row['image'];
$text=$row['text'];
    echo"<div>
        <img src='$image'>
        $text
    </div>
```

More specifically I'm looking for the difference in how PHP will add the text to the HTML dump on the front end.

Comment: nope, it's about how to use each one properly, because when using the . I've noticed that php will sometimes put the stuff at the end of the page, but with the , it sometimes won't.

Comment: But if you understand the differences then you know how to use them.

Comment: "sometimes put the stuff at the end of the page" - No, it doesn't. That only happens when mashing in user functions that print stuff out of expression context.

Comment: Don't things like while loops, and stuff do that on dumps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with period:

```
echo"<div>
        <img src='".$row['image']."'>
        ".$row['text']."
    </div>";
```

`src='".$row['image']."'` denotes the concatenation of `$row['image']`

> with comma:

```
echo"<div>
    <img src='",$row['image'],"'>
    ",$row['text'],"
</div>";
```

^The comma `,` defines the string separation in the above example.

> preset:

```
$image=$row['image'];
$text=$row['text'];
    echo"<div>
        <img src='$image'>
        $text
    </div>
```

^While this would still work with single `'$image'` A better practice would be `'".$row['image']."'` wrapped around quotes, i.e. below:

```
echo "<div>
    <img src='".$image."'>
    ".$text."
</div>";
```

> Note: Keeping it simple, `.` for concatenation and `,` for separation.

^An Example:

```
<?php
$str = "Hawas" . "Ka" . "Pujaari";

echo $str;

$str2 = "Hawas, " . "Ka, " . "Pujaari";

echo  $str2;
?>
```

Comment: Downvoted for what good reason?

Comment: Great explanation, since I was looking for the article answer, but maybe adding the dump (it adds inline/at the end/slower speed) would make it better.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Which part? Correct me so I can improve and do better? :)

Answer (score 3):

`.` concatenates strings (`+` in most languages, but not PHP). [PHP manual operators](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp)

`,` separates arguments (echo can take more than 1 argument). [PHP manual echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: Can you add detail to the explanation?

Comment: @PI of the operators?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example
`echo" ".$row['text']."` must be changed to 
`echo " ".$row['text']."` which is write syntax to concatenate two string.
For second example
`echo" ",$row['text'],"` must be changed to `echo " ",$row['text'],"` I don think this is valid syntax in php .
`$image=$row['image']; $text=$row['text']; echo" $text` must be like

`$image=$row['image']; $text=$row['text']; echo $text;`